# Flutter : (GetX) RxInt

Tags: flutter

I made a program that changes the shape when the button is pressed
I used (IndexedStack)
Each time the button is pressed, a different shape appears
But I get a lot of problems that I can't solve

```
IndexedStack(
index: controller.IndexedStackSelected.value,
children: [
Container(),
Container(),
]
),
```

The button

```
controller.buttontwo();
controller.buttonone();
```

type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'RxInt' of 'function result'

Controller

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {

  late int minutsave ;
  RxInt IndexedStackSelected = 0.obs;

  void buttonone() {
    IndexedStackSelected = 0 as RxInt;
  }

  void buttontwo() {
    IndexedStackSelected = 1 as RxInt;
  }
```

When I use (Obx) in the code it tells me :

[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this. And refer this code for GetX. [getx_controller_example](https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example/blob/main/lib/controllers/app_controller.dart)

```
IndexedStack(
index: controller.IndexedStackSelected,
children: [
Container(),
Container(),
]
),
```

//

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

var _indexedStackSelected = 0.obs;

int get IndexedStackSelected => _indexedStackSelected.value;

void buttonone() {
    _indexedStackSelected.value = 0;
  }

  void buttontwo() {
    _indexedStackSelected.value = 1;
  }
```